# Memory leak in perl

Tags: perl, memory-leaks

Below is the output of one of my tests using `Memory::Usage`.

```
time vsz ( diff) rss ( diff) shared ( diff) code ( diff) data ( diff)
0 264620 ( 264620) 95848 ( 95848) 8460 ( 8460) 4 ( 4) 85440 ( 85440) before
3 294668 ( 30048) 115552 ( 19704) 13728 ( 5268) 4 ( 0) 99808 ( 14368) after
```

Does this mean my code have large memory leak,as diffs are very much high ???

Can somebody please tell better ways to test memory leaks

Comment: Tim Bunce worked on Devel::SizeMe (http://blog.timbunce.org/2012/10/05/introducing-develsizeme-visualizing-perl-memory-use/ )  And he gave a talk on it at YAPC: http://youtu.be/GIIeOntmojg  It is very informative, and will change some of the things you thought you knew about memory management with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The diff column indicates the change in memory consumption, and when it grows too much, that's not a good sign.

Another way to test memory leaks is [Test::LeakTrace](http://p3rl.org/Test::LeakTrace).

Comment: what my understanding is , let say we call a function which allocates some memory and when the scope of function ends ideally memory should be deallocated and the diff should be 0 (means memory allocated = memory deallocated). Am i correct ?

Comment: Ideally the diff should be 0 but in practical it is not always possible.

Comment: also i tried using Test::Leaktrace but seems that was not able to use it properly can you guide to some  other better links related to this module